# Изменить название файла стартовой страницы

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Файловая система состоит из файлов с кириллическими именами. Что необходимо добавить в .htaccess, чтобы главным файлом директории был не **index.php**, а **главная.php**?

Comment: Можно ассоциировать с вопросом enSO: [How do I change the default index page in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322345/how-do-i-change-the-default-index-page-in-apache). Там есть настройка `DirectoryIndex`, но не знаю, как там с кириллицей, пробовали?

Comment: я изменил заголовок, потому что индексный файл это файл, в котором хранятся индексы

Comment: Поступая подобным образом, вы рискуете устроить себе веселенький глюкодром на ровном месте - как отнесется весь зоопарк софта, применяемого на вебе, к кириллическому и нестандартному имени главной страницы - вопрос везения.